# Problem with a quadratic equation and its condition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem but it seems I cannot find it. Anyway, here is an equation and its condition.

$x^2-2mx+m+1=0$

Condition: $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 4$

When I get to

$x_1+x_2 = 2m$

$x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 4$

I get stuck.

Comment: Hint: what does the constant term $m+1$ tell you about $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: @rogerl Well, I got that $x_1 * x_2 = m + 1$. I do not know if that has anything to do with what You have just asked me, but still...

Comment: @Sarich Use the fact that $x_1x_2=m+1$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak Alright, but can you explain to me how? I know I sound stupid, but I want to understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Sarich In general, a polynomial $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ of deg $n$ having roots $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ has the following relationships between its coefficient and roots: $\sum x_i=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}},\sum\limits_{i< j} x_ix_j=\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_n},$ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to the equation $x^2 -2mx + (m+1) = 0$, we have that

$(x - x_1)(x-x_2) = x^2 - 2mx + (m+1) \\ x^2 - (x_2 + x_1) x + x_1x_2 = x^2 -2mx + (m+1),$

which implies $x_1 + x_2 = 2m$ and $x_1x_2 = m+1$. Therefore,

$x^2_1 + x^2_2 = 4 \\
(x_1 + x_2)^2 - 2x_1x_2 = 4 \\
(2m)^2 - 2(m+1) = 4 \\
2m^2 - m - 3 = 0 \\
(m + 1)(2m-3) = 0,$

which implies $m_1 = -1$ and $m_2 = 3/2$.